# splitting string only integers with new line regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I have an string and try it parsing to string array. The string look like:

```
c: 00000
u: 00001
h: 0001
r: 0010
s: 0011
e: 010
i: 0110
n: 0111
```

The above example is about only one string reference like         `String str = testClass.toString();`
I merely want to put the 0 and 1's into a string array.

```
String filtered = str.replaceAll("[^0-1]","");
        String[] numbers = filtered.split("\n");
        for (String a : numbers) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

I wrote the above code but it gives just one line output. How can it be fixed?

```
000000000100010010001101001100111
```

I intend as

```
str[0] = "00000";
...
str[7] = "0111"
```

Comment: When you replaced everything that wasn't a 0 or 1, that included the line breaks, so trying to split on `"\n"` afterwards isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `'\n'` are also being replaced by an empty string when you call `str.replaceAll("[^0-1]","")`.

One possible approach is to replace all chars except digits AND `'\n'`:

```
String filtered = str.replaceAll("[^01\n]","");
String[] list = filtered.split("\n");
```

Another approach would be to directly split, keeping only `"0"` and `"1"`:

```
String[] list = str.split("[^01]+");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can strip non numbers and replace with a hyphen `-` and then split them on `-`.

```
String filtered = str.replaceAll("[^0-1]+","-");
        String[] numbers = filtered.split("-");
        for (String a : numbers) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
String filtered = str.replaceAll("[^0-1(\n)]","");
```

instead of

```
String filtered = `str.replaceAll("[^0-1]","");
```

Rest of your code is fine. Problem is, by using regex `[^0-1]` you are replacing everything except digits `0` and `1` with empty string. This in turn replaces `\n` as well with empty string `""` and hence all 0s and 1s get concatenated. You actually need to skip digits `0`, `1` and `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can use a single `split()` to get your array of numbers, but you will have to ignore the first value there (which is empty). his will be more efficient than using `split` + `replaceAll()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "c: 00000" + "\n" + "u: 00001" + "\n" + "h: 0001";
    System.out.println(s);
    String[] arr = s.split("\\D+");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

O/P :

```
c: 00000
u: 00001
h: 0001
[, 00000, 00001, 0001] // ignore the first empty value.
```